# Copy several files to current directory using find on busybox

Tags: linux, github-actions, busybox

I have the following snippet that works well non normal terminals (for example, on cygwin):

```
find . -name '*.aab' -or -name '*.apk' -exec cp '{}' ./ \;
```

What it should do is find all the files that match the provided patterns and copy them to the current directory.
However, when I run this terminal on Github Workflows it only copies the `.apk` files, like if it were ignoring the first item on the or. I know there are `aab` files because using another tool on the next step (upload artifacts) I'm able to target those files using the same glob. The problem of using upload artifacts directly with the glob is that the resulting zip will preserve the long and weird directory structure, and I want a flat zip file.

I think GithubAcitons uses busybox so, how can I accomplish that using busybox?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example using precedence ( ) works with Linux find and busybox find; note POSIX compliance with `-o` vs. -or

```
find . \( -name '*.aab' -o -name '*.apk' \) -exec stat '{}' +
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Why does it need to escape the `(` and why it ends with a `+` instead of `\;`?

Comment: I tried this `find . \( -name '*.aab' -o -name '*.apk' \) -exec cp '{}' ./ +` and it gives me the following error: `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Comment: ok, seems that when you want to provide several arguments you need to finish the command with `\;`. After that it worked perfectly